# Rails query parameter with same name as optional path parameter

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rails-routing

Suppose, I have this code in routes.rb

```
get "/items/(:brand)", to: "items#index", as: :items
```

I can't change this route, because sometimes I need urls with brand in path (not in query).
Can I create path like this:

```
/items?brand=TestBrand
```

but not this:

```
/items/TestBrand
```

via route helpers?

`items_path(brand: "TestBrand")` give 2'nd variant.

Comment: `get "/items/(:brand)", to: "items#index", as: :items` is a pretty bad route as it violates the RESTful conventions and  creates and ambiguity with the  normal show route (`GET /items/:id`). Why can't you change it to something better like `GET /brands/:brand_id/items`?

Comment: I need support large chunk with legacy code :(, in reality this code is much complicated than my example

Comment: Well then you need to decide if its time for a breaking change since the existing code may not actually work as intended.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is not a very good solution as it violates the RESTful conventions.

In Rails flavor REST `GET /resource_name/:id` maps to the show route. In the case of `get "/items/(:brand)", to: "items#index", as: :items` this creates an ambiguity (is the segment an item id or a brand?) when the router matches the requests and the first declared route will win which is hardly desirable.

A better solution is to declare it as a nested resource:

```
resources :brands, only: [] do
  resources :items, only: [:index], module: :brands
end
```

---

```
    Prefix Verb URI Pattern                       Controller#Action
brand_items GET  /brands/:brand_id/items(.:format) brands/items#index
```

---

```
# app/controllers/brands/items_controller.rb
module Brands
  class ItemsController < ::ApplicationController
    before_action :set_brand

    # GET /brands/:brand_id/items
    def index
      @items = @brand.items
    end

    def set_brand
      @brand = Brand.find(params[:brand_id])
    end
  end
end
```

Answer (score 0):

Additional parameters in "get" are supported by default, so maybe you could use

```
get "/items", to: "items#index", as: :items
```

or

```
resources :items, only: [:index]
```

And use path helper which you provided:

```
items_path(brand: "TestBrand")
```

Comment: ```get "/items/(:brand)", to: "items#index", as: :items```
See my question please, I need use route with conditional parameter

Comment: If you need both variants, add them to routes:
`get "/items", to: "items#index", as: :items`
and
`get "/items/(:brand)", to: "items#index", as: :brand_items`

BTW, max right, it is not very RESTfull. Maybe it would be better to think about changing behavior.

Answer (score 0):

To answer your question - Yes, you can

```
get "/items", to: "items#index", as: :items
```

and the following route helper will create

```
items_path(brand: "TestBrand")
#=> items?brand=TestBrand
```

**NOTE:**

If you are using:

```
recourses :items
```

You must alredy have this

Comment: ```get "/items/(:brand)", to: "items#index", as: :items```
I can't change this, because sometimes I need urls with brand in path (not in query)